# Keyword matching involving integers without leading zeros using sed and awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, replace, pattern-matching

Assume a multi-line textfile (`file1`) that contains one keyword per line, where each keyword has the format String*Integer*. The order of the lines is fixed.

```
$cat file1
foo1
foo2
foo4
foo10
```

Assume further a multi-line textfile (`file2`) whose lines contain several whitespace-delimited words, one of which may be one of the above-mentioned keywords. Every line can only contain one keyword, and the keyword may be located anywhere within the line, except as the last word. If a keyword exists in the line, then the term `baz=()` also exists in the line. The order of the lines is not fixed.

```
$cat file2
foo1 bar baz=()
bar foo4 baz=()
foo10 qux baz=()
foo2 baz=()
```

If a line in `file2` contains keyword *n*, I want to add the line number that keyword *n* has in `file1` in the term `baz=()`.

```
$sought_commands file1 file2
foo1 bar baz=(1)
bar foo4 baz=(3)
foo10 qux baz=(4)
foo2 baz=(2)
```

I came up with the following code, which has the flaw that keyword *foo1* masks the term `baz=()` for keyword *foo10*:

```
for kw in $(cat file1); do
    lineNumbr=$(cat file1 | awk '/'$kw'/{print NR; exit}')
    sed -i "/$kw/ s/baz\=()/baz\=($lineNumbr)/" file2
done
```

.

```
$cat file2
foo1 bar baz=(1)
bar foo4 baz=(3)
foo10 qux baz=(1) # ERROR!
foo2 baz=(2)
```

**Edit 1**: I considered using the circumstance that the keywords are always followed by a whitespace in `file2` as a delimiter, but then the awk-command fails:

```
for kw in $(cat file1); do
    kw_adj="$kw "
    lineNumbr=$(cat file1 | awk '/'$kw_adj'/{print NR; exit}')
    sed -i "/$kw_adj/ s/baz\=()/baz\=($lineNumbr)/" file2
done

awk: cmd. line:1: /foo1
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: /foo2
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: /foo4
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: /foo10
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ unterminated regexp
```

Comment: if you're looping file contents in bash and using `awk` (and `sed`) you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

> ```
> sed -i "/$kw/ s/baz\=()/baz\=($lineNumbr)/" file2
> ```

When the value of `kw` is "foo1", the pattern `/$kw/` matches "foo10" as well, replacing `foo10 qux baz=()` with `foo10 qux baz=()`. Once this is written to the file, `baz=()` will no longer exist, so when the "foo10" pattern is applied from the input, it will have nothing to replace.

Change that line like this:

```
sed -i "/\<$kw\>/ s/baz\=()/baz\=($lineNumbr)/" file2
```

The `\<...\>` makes a pattern match word boundaries.
This way "foo10" will not be matched by `/\<foo1\>/`, only the complete word "foo1".

Also, the `lineNumbr=$(...)` inside the loop is silly,
when you can already know the line number using simple counting:

```
lineNumbr=1
for kw in $(cat file1); do
    sed -i "/\<$kw\>/ s/baz\=()/baz\=($lineNumbr)/" file2
    ((lineNumbr++))
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Your solution is at the very level I can comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=NR; next} 
   /baz=\(\)$/ {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) 
                  if($i in a) sub(/\(\)$/,"(" a[$i] ")")}1' file{1,2}

foo1 bar baz=(1)
bar foo4 baz=(3)
foo10 qux baz=(4)
foo2 baz=(2)
```